# Weird way of importing Python turtle works but I don't know why

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I hope you will understand my question.

I noticed that I get the same results when I import turtle module in following two ways.

```
from turtle import Turtle
t=Turtle()
t.screen.bgcolor("black")
```

and also

```
import turtle
turtle.bgcolor("black")
```

I am confused about this, “from turtle import Turtle”.

According to what I know, it means “to import Turtle.py from turtle (folder / package)”.  I may be wrong, you can help me out to understand better.

But I can’t find any Turtle.py module. It is only turtle.py I saw.

What's weird about it is that it works.

Can anyone tell me why?

I am using Python version 3.6

Comment: `from turtle import Turtle` means you import the class `Turtle` from `turtle.py`

Comment: Thanks for your conribution.

Answer (score 0):

Python's turtle.py is unusual in that it presents both a function-based interface and an object-oriented interface.  Depending on how you import it, you can work with one, or the other, or both.

Here, we are using the object-oriented interface to invoke the screen *method* `bgcolor()`:

```
from turtle import Turtle

t = Turtle()
t.screen.bgcolor("black")
```

I usually write this as:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")

t = Turtle()
```

as having direct access to the Screen object simplifies things.  Using this style import, you cannot access the function-based interface.

When we do this simpler import, we have access to **both** the function-based interface and the object-oriented interface.  Here, we're using the *function* `bgcolor()` to set the background color:

```
import turtle

turtle.bgcolor("black")
```

Using either the function-based or object-oriented interface to turtle.py is fine, but you can get yourself seriously confused when mixing the two.

Comment: @GodsonRaptureChijioke, turtle.py is one of the standard libraries that comes with the basic Python installation.